# How can i show my battery level in AppWidget?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, battery

I want to show the battery level in my AppWidget. I used below code to get battery level in my activity

```
BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        int scale = -1;
        int level = -1;
        int voltage = -1;
        int temp = -1;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
                Log.d("Battery_level", ""+level);
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
```

How can i implement this in my Class which extends AppWidgetProvider?

```
public class HomeWidget1 extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[]  
  appWidgetIds) {
  super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
```

What should be the code in onUpdate and onReceive method??

Answer (score 2):

This code gives you the battery level:

```
package com.exercise.AndroidBattery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidBattery extends Activity {

private TextView batteryLevel, batteryVoltage, batteryTemperature,
   batteryTechnology, batteryStatus, batteryHealth;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       batteryLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterylevel);
       batteryVoltage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batteryvoltage);
       batteryTemperature = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterytemperature);
       batteryTechnology = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterytechology);
       batteryStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batterystatus);
       batteryHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.batteryhealth);

       this.registerReceiver(this.myBatteryReceiver,
         new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
   }

   private BroadcastReceiver myBatteryReceiver
   = new BroadcastReceiver(){

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  if (arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)){
   batteryLevel.setText("Level: "
     + String.valueOf(arg1.getIntExtra("level", 0)) + "%");
   batteryVoltage.setText("Voltage: "
     + String.valueOf((float)arg1.getIntExtra("voltage", 0)/1000) + "V");
   batteryTemperature.setText("Temperature: "
     + String.valueOf((float)arg1.getIntExtra("temperature", 0)/10) + "c");
   batteryTechnology.setText("Technology: " + arg1.getStringExtra("technology"));

   int status = arg1.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);
   String strStatus;
   if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){
    strStatus = "Charging";
   } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING){
    strStatus = "Dis-charging";
   } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){
    strStatus = "Not charging";
   } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){
    strStatus = "Full";
   } else {
    strStatus = "Unknown";
   }
   batteryStatus.setText("Status: " + strStatus);

   int health = arg1.getIntExtra("health", BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN);
   String strHealth;
   if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD){
    strHealth = "Good";
   } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT){
    strHealth = "Over Heat";
   } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD){
    strHealth = "Dead";
   } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE){
    strHealth = "Over Voltage";
   } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE){
    strHealth = "Unspecified Failure";
   } else{
    strHealth = "Unknown";
   }
   batteryHealth.setText("Health: " + strHealth);

  }
 }

   };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But my question is how to implemnt this in AppWidget??